# iOS - UIView does not display inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uistackview

I have a `UIStackView` which needs a background color in one of the stacks, so I placed a `UIView` inside, but the `UIView` is never displayed. The `UIView` currently has one subview, a `UILabel`, but should eventually have another `UIStackView` instead. If I display the `UILabel` as a direct child of the `UIStackView`, rather than the `UIView`, then the `UILabel` displays properly. So, what constraints are missing or wrong on my `UIView`?

```
                        let stack = UIStackView()
                        stack.axis = .Vertical
                        stack.alignment = .Leading
                        stack.distribution = .EqualCentering
                        stack.spacing = 0

                        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

                        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 50)
                        let viewHolder = UIView(frame: frame)
                        viewHolder.backgroundColor = blueColor

                        //Needs a blue background
                        let name = UILabel()
                        name.text = nameText
                        name.textColor = yellowColor
                        name.backgroundColor = blueColor
                        name.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(32.0)                        

                        let address = UILabel()
                        address.text = addressText

                        let dateTime = UILabel()
                        dateTime.text = calString

                        viewHolder.addSubview(name)
                        stack.addArrangedSubview(viewHolder)
                        stack.addArrangedSubview(address)
                        stack.addArrangedSubview(dateTime)

                        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(stack)
```

And when run it produces this:

[image: No UIView, or UILablel]

If I remove the UIView from the equation, ie:

```
                        let stack = UIStackView()
                        stack.axis = .Vertical
                        stack.alignment = .Leading
                        stack.distribution = .EqualCentering
                        stack.spacing = 0

                        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

                        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 50)
                        let viewHolder = UIView(frame: frame)
                        viewHolder.backgroundColor = blueColor

                        //Needs a blue background
                        let name = UILabel()
                        name.text = nameText
                        name.textColor = yellowColor
                        name.backgroundColor = blueColor
                        name.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(32.0)                        

                        let address = UILabel()
                        address.text = addressText

                        let dateTime = UILabel()
                        dateTime.text = calString

                        //viewHolder.addSubview(name)
                        stack.addArrangedSubview(name) //Add the label directly to the UIStackView
                        stack.addArrangedSubview(address)
                        stack.addArrangedSubview(dateTime)

                        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(stack)
```

I get:
[image: UILables showing, but no UIVIew]

I just need the blue part to stretch across the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answer is, don't use UIStackView. Use the built in UITableView for this kind of layout.

Comment: You need to update the intrinsicContentSize of the UIView so the stackView knows it's initial frame before it can stretch it horizontally. I'm guessing the intrinsicContentSize of your UIView was being returned as {0,0} causing this behaviour.